# Cordova inappbrowser fails to load page

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, inappbrowser

I am trying to create a OAuth login flow. In a Cordova app (tested only on Android), I try to load a page from my server which redirects the browser to the correct OAuth page on google's side. However, this abruptly stopped working.

**If you try the url in the code below in a browser, you may want to go incognito or try some other measure to avoid autologging in. (The server creates an account to an indev service if you actually log in.)**

If I write the code like this (I omit the fishing of the credentials tokens from the URL, this is the simplest reproducible example.):

```
function onLoad(){
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
  var authWindow = cordova.InAppBrowser.open("https://dev.taskapp.io/googleURI", '_blank');
  authWindow.addEventListener("loadstart", function(e){
      alert("Loadstart fired")
  }
)
}
```

The webview remains empty and the message Loadstart fired appears once. If I swap `'_blank'` to to `'_self'` or `'_system'`, the pages load and the redirects work but the events never fire. This happens only with the given page.

I am at my wit's end.

**Update:** the same code works like a charm on iOS. On android using `window.open()` also fails.

**Update 2**: I now understand, that `_system` opens the os's browser, which I obviously have no control over and that `_self` squishes whatever was in the webview, rendering my listeners to nothingness. `_blank` works once from a cleanly cloned repository and then breaks on a second build (without code change).

If I substitute the url in the `cordova.InAppBrowser.open(...)` to the one my server redirects from, Google's tech loads. However the final login button (which would trigger the redirection to my server, one can assume.) is dead.

Does redirecting the _blank target break things? Is this a bug? Is someone else experiencing this?

Comment: what kind of return does open() give you? if it's a _window_, then that window get destroyed when you load the next page.

Comment: My apologies, what do you exactly mean? That the redirection destroys the window? At least the screen becomes white.

Comment: did you ever fix this issue?